# invalid conversion from time_t to const time_t*

Tags: c++

```
time_t raw_time = time(NULL);
tm* current_time = localtime(&raw_time);
```

I got the answer myself... I totally messed up the warnings. Thanks anyway.

Comment: can you post what the answer is close your ticket?  This anyone doing a search can see the answer.

Comment: Sure! I'll post the answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

localtime requires an argument of "time_t*" which is a pointer. So you have to put the & there.

Answer (score 4):

The `localtime()` function dates back to when `(int)` was 16 bits and passing `(long)` on the stack was not widely supported; as such, it was specified to pass `(long *)`, which at the time was 16 bits.  It's been left as is because changing it would break enormous amounts of code.  You'll find that most of the time-related functions do this, since they were the only functions at the time that used `(long)`.  (`lseek()` came later.  Care to guess what non-`(long)`-using function it replaced?)

Comment: Aside:  one conclusion you can draw from this is that they *were* thinking ahead when they used `(long)` for times — just not nearly far *enough* ahead.  Not that it mattered, since given that `(long)` was dicey, `(long long)` was impossible.